# Problems scraping all data within a table

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm having some issues getting all the data I need from two specific html tables.  Tables at the bottom of this post.

The code above states html table id "table1". I also need to grab values from a table called "table2" in the exact same format.  I have tried this code and can extract the td values but not the few values that are within the span specifiers within the td. I've tried multiple ways to do this but I'm just not getting it. My code looks something like:

```html
$dom = file_get_html("internets.html);
         
         //not sure how to specify the table exactly!? because this code didn't work.
         //$tds = $dom->find('table[id=table1]',0)->find('tr');
         
         foreach($dom->find('tr') as $key => $tr)
         {   
           
            $td = $tr->find('td');
            echo $td[0]->innertext . "</br>";
          
         }
```

Any assistance much appreciated. I have done some searching here and also used the simple php dom manual.

Here is the format of a table:

```html
    <table id="table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Prev Close:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    0.02

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Open:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    0.02

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Bid:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
                    <span id="yfs_b00_pgo.ax">

                        0.0180

                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row"></th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    1y Target Est:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Beta:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="54%" scope="row">

                    Next Earnings Date:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$html=<<<XHTML
<table id="table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Prev Close:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    0.02

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Open:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    0.02

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Bid:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
                    <span id="yfs_b00_pgo.ax">

                        0.0180

                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row"></th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    1y Target Est:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="48%" scope="row">

                    Beta:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="54%" scope="row">

                    Next Earnings Date:

                </th>
                <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">

                    N/A

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
XHTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query("/*//table[@id='table1'//*/td") as $i=>$node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}

?>
```